# Moodle 3.3.2 ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: php, moodle

I've installed successfully Moodle version 3.3.2 and at the end, i got an error to connection database. But as i've seen it generated all tables in database moodle.
Now, i can't enter, ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on loading pages. 
URL:    http://example.com/admin/index.php?cache=1.

Additional Server information:

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
PHP: 5.6
Mysql: 5.7.20-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Delete all the data from moodledata folder (Try this only with the new instance otherwise will loose the data), then try to open yourdomain/moodle in your browser. It will work.

Comment: Yeah, that's work i wanna understand that when i open the Main Page, it shows just a link to Login and nothing else. I suppose that it should be show the calendar and List of courses in the main page and Login form. Is it correct?

Comment: It depends on the frontpage settings. Normally the index page list the available courses and login link on right top corner.

Answer (score 6):

Different approach to solving this problem after checking and making sure that apache and php configuration are ok. I the added this line of code to my noodle config file.
$CFG->sslproxy = true;

And this resolved the issue.

Comment: This has done the trick for me, many thanks mate!

Comment: It worked, thanks, but what does it do.

Answer (score 2):

go on your server directory such as "www=>moodle directory=>admin
open index.php
find following
"redirect("index.php?sessionstarted=1&lang=$CFG->lang");"
and comment it
i find this on line 712 in moodle 3.7. it might be changed with version
save file and refresh page

Answer (score 1):

Search the moodledata directory, enter it and delete the following directories

- cache
- localcache

Answer (score 0):

in my case, this error come out because of the disk was full and yes deleting cache and localcache solve the problem

Comment: Please provide explanation or cite with some article to your answer.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekGurjar, I was come to this page and trying to delete the cache and localcache in moodledata, but the error come again after few minutes then I figure it out that the server disk was full, that's why deleting cache and localcache was working because it empties some space.